# How can I make console.log(sum(1)) // 1 and console.log(sum(1,2)(3)) //6 work?

Tags: javascript

**sum**
How can I make console.log(sum(1))// 1 and console.log(sum(1,2))// 3 and console.log(sum(1,2)(3))  //6 work?

Comment: What does your `sum` function look like?

Comment: What are you trying to do? All I see above is invalid Javascript syntax. If you're trying to use a `sum` function, it doesn't exist. You can simply use `+` to add numbers, though.

Comment: Go through the concepts of **function curying** in js. you can create the function according to your question

Answer (score 4):

Return a function that, when stringified, returns a number in a closure, which gets added to when the function is called:

```js
const sum = (...args) => {
  let thisSum = 0;
  const fn = (...args) => {
    thisSum += args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    return fn;
  };
  fn.toString = () => thisSum;
  return fn(...args);
};

console.log(sum(1)) // 1 
console.log(sum(1, 2)) // 3 
console.log(sum(1, 2)(3)) //6
```